# Checking all values in an array

Tags: c++, arrays

I have an array of numbers like this:

```
int array[5];
```

I am trying to break out of a while loop. I basically want to say if all numbers in the array are greater than 100 then end the loop.

Is there a way to process that?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: There is a function, probably more than one, [in `<algorithm>` that does what you need.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm)

Comment: How about using `break`?

Comment: What `while` loop? What relation does it bear to that array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check every element in the array and break if only the element is smaller than 100.

And outside the loop print the message based on whether `i` - The loop counter- is equal to the size or not. If equal than all elements are greater otherwise one of them is smaller:

```
int array[] = {271, 120, 469, 77, 2000};
//int array[] = {271, 120, 469, 787, 2000}; // uncomment this line and comment out the line above to see the difference.


int i = 0; 
for(; i < 5; i++)
    if(100 > array[i])
        break;

if(i != 5)
    std::cout << "Not all the values are greater than 100" << std::endl;
else
    std::cout << "All the values are greater than 100" << std::endl;
```

Comment: Since this is C++ it would still be better to use the standard library where possible, in this case std::all_of from <algorithm> as suggested by @user4581301