# Break out of Loop with Array Condition

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, for-loop, if-statement

I'm currently making a Chutes and Ladders game for class. The win condition for this game is if a player lands on Square 100, they win. If they happen to go past 100, they stay there until everyone finishes the game (Either someone lands on 100 or everyone goes past 100). I'm having trouble breaking out of the while loop if EVERYONE is past 100.

There's a lot of code so I'll simplify as much as I can. Under !!!HERE IS THE PROBLEM!!!! is where I need help.

Is there a way to specify once ALL the elements in an array are ABOVE 100 to break? Sorry if the question is a repeat...this post has a lot more detail.

```
string name[MAXplayers]; //Array to store names
int position[MAXplayers]; //Array to store board position

unsigned seed; //Random Number Generator Seed
seed = time(0); //Set seed to 0
srand(seed); //Call srand function

int spin;
bool done = false;
int counter = 0;
const int WIN = 100;

while (done != true)
{
    if (counter == WIN)
    {
        cout << "That's it, game over!" << endl << endl;
        done = true;
    }
    else 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < players; i++)
        {
            if (position[i] > WIN) //!!!!!HERE IS THE PROBLEM!!!!!!
            {
                cout << "Sorry " << name[i] << "! You can't move! You're stuck at " << position[i] << endl << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << name[i] << "'s turn! Pres [Enter] to spin the wheel!";
                cin.get();
                spin = rand() % 12 + 1;
                cout << "You spun the number " << spin << "!" << endl;

                int temploc = position[i] += spin;
etc...etc...etc...etc...etc...etc...
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check ALL Array Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46921042/check-all-array-values)

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm: Indeed - that question should have been amended instead of being re-asked. I closed the original instead.

Answer (score 0):

To break out of the inter `for` loop when your WIN condition is met, you can use the keyword **break**. This will stop the loop processing regardless of the conditional on the `for` loop.

Note however after breaking out, the program will still iterate around your `while` loop until it's conditional `done != true` is met.

Comment: Ultimately it would be fantastic if I could break out of the while loop if I can do this

    while (position for ALL players > 100)

Comment: @G.Nguyen: You're describing the function `while(std::all_of(...` but I suspect you actually want to continue playing _until_ all positions >= 100, or _while any_ position < 100.